# Multi host and ports IdMappedPortTCP delphi 7

Tags: delphi, indy

I am making a program that detects a url and redirects it to another host using the Idmappedporttcp component, because looking for the solution to redirect to a host, in the Onconect event, well redirects but the problem is how I can get the request to see if it should be redirected. my code is this.

```
procedure TForm1.idmpdprtcp1Connect(AThread: TIdMappedPortThread);


begin
if athread.NetData > '' then//Returns me blank data
begin
  (*
  as I returned no data I can not check if it should be redirected to another host.
  *)
  end;
 with TIdTCPClient(AThread.OutboundClient) do
begin
Host := 'server.com';
Port := 80;

end;
end;
```

Excuse me for my bad English. I hope an idea thanks.

Comment: reme lebua helpi please you are master in indy project :( excuse me please:

Comment: `TIdMappedPortTCP` is a passthrough of raw bytes, it has no concept of higher-level protocols, like HTTP. You would have to parse the raw `NetData` as needed to discover the URL being requested, and then you can configure the `OutboundClient` as needed. If you are indeed using HTTP, you should consider using `TIdHTTPProxyServer` instead of `TIdMappedPortTCP`, and do the redirection in the `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event, which gives you access to a `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext` that describes the requested URL and headers.

Comment: This code as found in this page as you say it should be discussed in crude oil in netdata and that want to analyze it according to this this post where you mention http://www.delphigroups.info/2/12/211739.html

This code as found in this page as you say it should be discussed in crude oil in netdata and that want to analyze it according to this this post where you mention said that if it is possible to view the headers and redirect to a new host using idmappedporttcp but I can not see the netdata crude I appreciate any other suggestions to do this preferably with idmappedporttcp

Comment: If you re-read that DelphiGroups discussion more carefully, it does not say to use `NetData` in the `OnConnect` event. `NetData` is only available in the `OnExecute` and `OnOutboundData` events. To reconfigure the `OutboundClient` in the `OnConnect` event based on the request data (before any `NetData` is received), you will have to manually read the request data from `AContext.Connection.IOHandler` directly until the request URL is known, caching any data you read so you can send it to the `OutboundClient.IOHandler` in the `OnOutboundConnect` event before the first `OnExecute` event is fired

Comment: Again, *IF* you are trying to implement a redirect for an HTTP request, try using `TIdHTTPProxyServer` instead of `TIdMappedPortTCP.`

Comment: I use 9 indy to be a little more easy to use and acontext this version does not contain it. and you tell me to use Tidhttproxyserver use it but the problem is that it does not support https in spite of configure the iohandler that use https does not work. That is why I prefer to use the idmappedporttcp instead of the idhttproxyserver component

a question is it possible to see raw netdata, the Onconnect event?

Comment: I already answered that in an earlier comment.  NO, you cannot use `NetData` in the `OnConnect` event, no data has been read yet at that time. You have to read the request manually from `AThread.Connection` directly instead.

Comment: `TIdHTTPProxyServer` in Indy 9 *does* support HTTPS for the inbound connection, but yes, now I see it does not support HTTPS on the outbound connection. But that should be easy to fix in the `OnConnect` event, by creating your own `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` objects, link them together, and assign the client to `TIdMappedPortThread(AThread).OutboundClient`.  `TIdHTTPProxyServer` will not create its own client object if you provide your own.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, as I can read directly from athread.connection? You can provide me with an example thank you.

Comment: I'm not here to write all of that code for you. Please do some research to learn how HTTP actually works, and learn how Indy socket I/O works, then look at how `TIdMappedPortTCP` and `TIdHTTPProxyServer` are implemented, especially in terms of HTTP, and then you can implement the reading logic yourself.  Come back to StackOverflow if you have new questions about it.

Comment: Thank you okay. I decided to install indy 10 because less was the problem, now use idhttproxyserver as in this example. 
http://pastebin.com/Mf5R6XSP
the remote host is where I check with idmappedporttcp in raw, but happens that in the event idhttproxyserver onconnect function-not part of the code do not redirect

Comment: That is not a valid `TIdHTTPProxyServer` example. `TIdHTTPServer` does not use `TIdMappedPortContext`, it uses `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext` instead. In any case, that example is just plain wrong in general. Do not try to redirect the `OutboundClient` in the `TIdHTTPProxyServer.OnConnect` event at all. Let `TIdHTTPProxyServer` read and parse the request headers for you, then it will fire the `OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event, where you can then perform your `OutboundClient` logic as needed. `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.Target` tells you the URL being requested...

Comment: ... , which is pre-parsed into the `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.OutboundClient.Host/Port` and `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.Document` properties. There is also a `TIdHTTPProxyServerContext.Headers` property as well.

Comment: Thank you but best segui trying with idmappedporttcp in the Onconnect event and as you said that it was in athread.connection then I did in indy 10, works Gets the string but no longer sends the request? associate the code thank you again for your patience

http://pastebin.com/4AtZsJGf

Comment: Go re-read my *second* comment earlier in this discussion.  I already covered that exact issue.  Please, no more questions here, this discussion has gotten too long and too far off-topic of the original question. I already explained how these components are intended to be used. If you have additional questions, please post new questions for them separately.